# Itext - Issue hiding elements when parsing html

Tags: java, itext

For a project at work I need to generate a pdf file from html.
I'm using Itext (Java) for this but I'm experiencing problems when trying to hide some elements.

The html is generated by some rich text element, an example of the htlm output that needs to be parsed:

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
Test
<br />
<div class="messageReply">
  <div class="messageReplyDate">18/12/2014 21:06</div>
  <div class="messageReplySubject">RE: Great Design</div>
  <div class="messageReplyInfo"><strong>Van: </strong>Projector Test user
    <br /><strong>Aan: </strong>Projector Test user
    <br />
  </div><span style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</span>
  <br
  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="messageReply">
    <div class="messageReplyDate">17/12/2014 15:17</div>
    <div class="messageReplySubject">RE: Great Design</div>
    <div class="messageReplyInfo"><strong>Van: </strong>Projector Test user
      <br /><strong>Aan: </strong>Projector Test user
      <br />
    </div>
    <br /> <b><i><u>Test</u></i></b>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="messageReply">
      <div class="messageReplyDate">13/08/2004 17:20</div>
      <div class="messageReplySubject">Great Design</div>
      <div class="messageReplyInfo"><strong>Van: </strong>Ashe
        <br /><strong>Aan: </strong>Brock
        <br /><strong>Cc: </strong>Prof. Oak
        <br />
      </div>Help :(</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To hide the elements I'm using following simple css file:

**css**

```
.messageReplySubject {
display: none !important;
}
```

Problem is, this just doesn't work.
Although, when I change the css file to this:

```
.messageReplySubject {
font-size: 30px;
}
```

It DOES change the font-size to 30px.
I've also tried some other methods like visibility: hidden, width: 0, ... but none of them do what I want.

Are display and visibility not supported or is there something I'm missing here?

I've uploaded a little test project so it's easier to see what's going on and more importantly, what goes wrong.

[PdfTest project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_BID_F_j3mHRDVwTG9WSERLbVk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The FlyingSaucer project will convert HTML to PDF with a couple oflines of code if you are interested in a simpler solution. https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alan, unfortunately I don't think flying saucer offers everything I want it to do. 

The pdf I'm generating is a combination of the parsed html and some more info I add programmatically, all gathered from a json object.

Answer (score 0):

My fear was very real, PdfDivs don't have borders so the css border attribute isn't supported too, obviously.

Those wondering what is supported can refer to [the table right here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141227023821/http://demo.itextsupport.com:80/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm).

**edit (3/1/18):** Updated css conformance list url

Comment: have you found any other way out to hide the element ? Also your provided link isn't working anymore.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the broken link, I updated it to the web archive url from around the time the post was originally made.


I've solved this by removing the unwanted elements from the html string myself before generating the pdf.
This is the only solution I could come up with to work around this issue.